# Running ruby gems on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, vagrant

I am on Windows 7 and want to use http://hospice.io/. This requires Ruby gem `librarian` so I installed ruby 2.0 using http://rubyinstaller.org/ then downloaded RubyGems 1.8.25 from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126 and updated (`gem update --system`). I installed `librarian`.

```
ruby setup.rb
gem install librarian
```

Now I am in the folder with my Vagrant box and want to do command `librarian-chef` but I get

```
'librarian-chef' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried it when running ruby `devkit/msys` with the same result. Any suggestions how to run it please? I would guess there is a problem with PATH but when `gem install` works why doesn't `librarian-chef` work too?

`gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/bin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/bin/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/bin/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/bin/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - C:/Users/Andrew/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: I think you should update your rubygems version as ruby 2 is supported by rubygems 2 and up

Comment: I see. I updated rubygems and reinstalled librarian. Still the same problem.

Comment: My `librarian-chef` works and I used RubyInstaller too (with Ruby 1.9.3, I remember there are problems with Chef on Ruby 2.0...), will look how my PATH is formed.

Comment: I have *C:\Tools\Ruby193\bin* in my `PATH` which is where `gem` and others reside and there is `librarian-chef` too

Comment: Ok, I'll try Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I reinstalled to Ruby 1.9.3 and rubygems 1.8.25. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you lookup where the `librarian-chef.bat` file is located on your system?

Comment: I run a search and nothing was found.

Comment: Should I run all these commands in the devkit/msys environment or in cmd.exe? Is it important?

Comment: I use normal cmd.exe, sometimes launched from the explorer.

Comment: Ok, that's not where the problem is.

Comment: Make sure that `$GEM_HOME` is in your `$PATH`. I haven't had this issue on Windows before, but this has almost always been the reason why I had trouble running gem executables on Linux. Also, notice that gem itself isn't installed in `$GEM_HOME`, which explains why it works but other gem commands don't.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy To be more precise: Ensure that ``%GEM_HOME%\bin`` is in your PATH.
But your hint lead me to the solution anyway, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Also, might want to add that I started development on a Windows machine back in ruby 1.8.7 and through ruby 1.9.3 and then switched to Ubuntu 12.04.  My development time probably cut in half or maybe even a quarter.  I don't know if this has changed with Ruby 2+

I encourage you to look at having a dual boot with Ubuntu, the small investment in setup will save you TONS of time in dealing with making windows act like linux and give you the added benefit of setting up your development environment exactly like it will be in production if you will be running something like unicorn/nginx.